# Should I be using goroutines with http.ListenAndServe?

Tags: go, goroutine

If I'm using `http.ListenAndServe` to provide responses when the user hits a URL, should I be firing off the corresponding actions in the function as a goroutine ?

For instance, say I'm listening at `/`:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", provideMainContent)
}

func provideMainContent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    /// Bunch of code, looks up details in databases, parses, then returns
}
```

Should the bunch of code in `provideMainContent` be wrapped in a goroutine so it doesn't slow down any potential requests that come after the fact ?

Comment: the method ListenAndServe() does that for you, we don't have to deal with that just remember that each handler is running in a different goroutine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer, No

GoDoc from `http.Serve` :

`Serve accepts incoming HTTP connections on the listener l, creating a new service goroutine for each. The service goroutines read requests and then call handler to reply to them.`

However as mentioned in the question linked by `@Mellow Marmot`, there might be cases where you might want to spawn a goroutine to do some processing while you return from the handler so that the requester does not have to wait for all the processing to be done to get a response.